# SwiftData: Type 'Schema.Relationship.Option' has no member 'cascade'

Tags: swift, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

We have a Swiftdata model such as:

```
@Model
class MyThing {

   var name:String

   var myObject: MyCustomObject

   //...

}
```

In order for "myObject" (which is also an @Model) to automatically get deleted when an instance of MyThing is deleted, we need to add the attribute(?), Relationship(.cascade) to myObject.

This is shown in this tutorial:

[image]

... and this Apple video:

[image]

But when I try to do it, this happens (there seems to be no option to do it)... and if I manually type it out it says it's not found:

[image]

Comment: Your question is not related to SwiftUI in any way. It's only about SwiftData. By needlessly adding SwiftUI to the question and tags you limit those who may otherwise find the question useful.

Comment: Thank you I thought SwiftData was only for SwiftUI. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those resources you found are out of date. There should be an argument label `deleteRule:`.

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
```

See also the signature of the macro in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/relationship(_:deleterule:minimummodelcount:maximummodelcount:originalname:inverse:hashmodifier:)).

```
macro Relationship(
    _ options: Schema.Relationship.Option...,
    deleteRule: Schema.Relationship.DeleteRule = .nullify,
    minimumModelCount: Int? = 0,
    maximumModelCount: Int? = 0,
    originalName: String? = nil,
    inverse: AnyKeyPath? = nil,
    hashModifier: String? = nil
)
```

Without an argument label, the compiler thought `.cascade` was passed to the `options` parameter.

Comment: Why does Apple's documentation not include the deleteRule argument label? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches

Comment: @NSSpeedForce Well we are only human, and mistakes happen. Presumably `@Relationship(.cascade)` was valid at some point during development, and then they changed the design but forgot to update the documentation.